# put iddossier as a foreign key in the file table (the right solution) or idfichier as a foreign key in the folder relationship?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

For the design of a database I have a one-to-many relationship. It would be a folder to several files and a file belongs to a folder.

Which should I do and why--put iddossier as a foreign key in the file table (the right solution) or idfichier as a foreign key in the folder relationship?

```
CREATE TABLE dossier(
    nomDossier VARCHAR(60),
    iddossier integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(iddossier)
 );

 CREATE TABLE fichier(
    nomFichier VARCHAR(60),
    idfichier integer,
    dossierid integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(idfichier),
    CONSTRAINT fichier_fk FOREIGN KEY(dossierid) REFERENCES dossier(iddossier)
  );
```

Comment: What is your 1 question about how & why you are 1st stuck, following what published DB design method, presented in what reference? PS Basic questions are faqs. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)
PS It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question.